# Targeting and Segmentation option in BCC is missing

Tags: atg, bcc, targeting

I have done set-up for Commerce site using CRS as base. But facing one issue. I do not see 'Targeting and Segmentation' option in BCC. What could be the issue? Pl note that i can start both pub and prod server instances successfully and also able to access ACC/BCC/my store etc.

Only missing part is, i do see 'Targeting and Segmentation' option under Personalization in BCC. I am using ATG 10.0.3. Any pointers/links to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the DPS module didn't get picked up while the Dynamo has started. Can you check from the Installed Products in Dyn/Admin page and see if DPS is included. If not manually include the module in the module list of the Publishing ear and deploy.